# Timeout during install on an Acer Aspire 5742G

Tags: installation, setup, timeout

I bought a new laptop and wanted to install ubuntu 11.10 64bit on it, but it always ends in a timeout.

Memory test was okay. But it won't install or boot the graphical interface. The USB Stick is brand new.

No it has no connection to the internet.

Intel Core i3 
nvidia Geforce GT520M 
4gb DDR3 Ram
320 gb

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "ends in a timeout"? is this a specific message you see on the screen?

Comment: We need  more information to help you. what is the brand of the laptop, what are the steps you are taking to install ubuntu, did you try to run it without installing first? there is any message being displayed. Did u check the number os partitions taken by the installed OS, some of the new Laptops come with 4 partitions what is the max aloud by the bios, and wont let you install except if you change this.

Comment: Acer Aspire 5742G-374G32Mnrr I boot from usb and try to install ubuntu. It doesn't matter if I try to install or boot it without installation it won't move and ends in a timeout. The only message is timeout and timeout and timeout with various numbers. Partition by the installed OS? Don't know. Four partition? Why?

Comment: It has only one partition. At least I can't see anything else.

Comment: timeout: killing '/sbin/modprobe -bv pci:v000010DEd00001244sv00003842sd00001556bc03sc00i00' [300] sometimes its [321] or anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In instllation disk menu press F6 for "other options" and disable acpi by selecting acpi=off (also you can select "noapic" "nolapic", but i think its not necessary), fnd try to boot ubuntu. 
If there is no more errors you can install ubuntu.
Also after installation I had problem with wifi - it was disabled by hardware and there is no way to turn it on.
So i replace "acpi=off" with "pci=noacpi" in my /boot/grub/grub.cfg (it should be added to the end of the line which contains "quiet splash" without qoutes)

PS. after installing system you should boot with one of this optionsб or system will not boot.
you can add them directly from grub menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, this issue is resolved in the recently released 12.04 beta. Aspire 5750g I've got had this same problem and just installed the new release without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Much better news:
The 12.04 beta 64 bit distro installed fine on the Acer Aspire 5742G. The non recovery mode runs in native resolution but screen backlight remains at maximum. Designated Fn + control keys invoke bargraph but with no actual results for display brightness. Power management appears to function quickly dimming the screen before turning off the display.

Answer (score 0):

Is that right, that you try to install Ubuntu with a USB Stick?
What says the installation with a CD/DVD???

--> try an installation with a 32bit version only to see if it hangs or not

Comment: CD/DVD doesn't work either.

Comment: 32 bit hangs too.

Answer (score 0):

this can be useful

http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions